# Which application controls the power management?

Tags: 11.10, power-management, gnome-power-manager

I'm using xmonad in Ubuntu Oneiric without the Unity desktop. In 11.04 I launched manually the gnome-power-manager for controlling the laptop battery but in the new Ubuntu this application is no longer available.

Which application controls now the power management in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the individual applications that you previously saw in the *system settings* you saw in Natty (11.04) have now been gathered together under the banner of the `gnome-control-center`

Thus to launch the Power Manager from the command line you need to run

```
gnome-control-center power
```

The way I found this was to run `gnome-control-center` - double click on the setting you want and then type `ps -ef | grep gnome-control-center` to see what the process is being run e.g.

```
ps -ef | grep gnome-control-center
dad       2158  1592  0 21:07 ?        00:00:00 gnome-control-center power
```